# JPA/Hibernate lazy loaded list is empty after flush()

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I've come accross a very strange JPA/Hibernate (v5.4.28) issue and was hoping, that someone could give me a hint how to approach this. The scenario is a bit complex to explain but I'll try to simplify it.

---

I have four entities, all with `FetchType.LAZY`:

- `AddressEntity`
- `StudentEntity` -> has a `List<AddressEntity>` with `fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL`
- `CourseEntity` -> has a `List<AttendingEntity>` with `fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL`
- `AttendingEntity` -> has a reference to `StudentEntity`, `AddressEntity` (must be one of the student's) & `CourseEntity` - all with `fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST`

I'm fetching a `CourseEntity` from the database using the entitymanger and use the getters to access the various nested entities.
Since they're all linked via `@ManyToOne` or `@OneToMany` I can get each student's addresses by getting the course's antending list, getting the student and then calling get on the address list.

However, if I call the entitymanger's flush() method after fetching the `CourseEntity` but *BEFORE* triggering the lazy load of the course's `AttendingEntity` list, JPA will still load the attending list and trigger the lazy loading for each student, *BUT* no lazy loading will be triggered for the student's list of `AddressEntity` and the size of the address list of a student is always zero.

---

Does anyone have a clue to why the flush seems to "break" the lazy loading here?

Is this expected behavior?

Are my annotations wrong or is there another annotation/property I need to set?

Thx a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out what caused this behaviour (even though I'm still not sure if that's expected behavior or a bug).
Apparently the problem was that I initialized all of my instance variable lists in the entities, so e.g.

```
public StudentEntity 
{
   // ...

    @OneToMany(...)
    private List<AddressEntity> = new ArrayList<>;
}
```

Somehow this seems to "confuse" Hibernate during some lazy loads. When I removed `new ArrayList<>` the issue seemed to be resolved.

Edit: I've found the "official" hibernate bug too
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14549

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug. Please create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.